# Make an Android button without using an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, android

Do someone know how to make the following code without using anonymous inner class ?

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

Comment: You can have your class implement OnClickListener then `button.setOnClickListener(this)`. You could also use butterknife to inject view's.

Comment: @X.LINK please learn to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [Accept Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) on StackOverFlow, it will encourage users to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could also write your own class implementing `View.OnClickListener`, if you want to reuse it in different activities.

```
class MyListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

and then use it via

```
button.setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
```

or create a `MyListener` object, that you can reuse:

```
MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
// ...
button.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `android:onClick="anyMethodName"` attribute for your button
in your layout file, for example:

```
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:onClick="myMethod"
                android:text="Update" />
```

and in your Class create a method with same name like this:

```
public void myMethod(View v){  // must use same name as in XML

  // Perform action on click, this works like onClick() of anonymous inner class
  Toast.makeText(this, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Just put whatever you wanted to put in your `onClick()` of anonymous inner class in above method and it will work like a charm.

One other way is to implement `OnClickListener` interface and then simply put all your logic in a single `onClick(View v)` method, by registering its listener like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Uh, can you detail the logic part ? I'm doing "public void myMethod((Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.strScnBtn))" but its all red.

Comment: don't use `Button` as the parameter, use `View` like i have

Answer (score 1):

There is also the option of having your `Activity` / `Fragment` implement `OnClickListener`. Then you can use a switch case to check the id of the view that has been clicked and execute the desired logic.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want an anonymous inner class? If it is an issue of code style you can try using [ButterKinfe](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Here is an example of how it would be used in an Activity (you can use it in any other class as well)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKinfe.inject(this); // This is where the listeners on set on the views
    }

    // Simple use case
    @OnClick(R.id.button_id)
    void onButtonClicked() {
        //Do something with button
    }

    // If you want the view paramater in the callback just add it!
    @OnClick(R.id.other_button_id)
    void onOtherButtonClicked(View otherButton) {
        //Do something with button
    }

}
```